# Color of title bar

Tags: android

How to change the color of the title bar by clicking a button. I would have a group of buttons to represent different colors once one of the button is clicked it should change the color of the title bar for all the activities in the application.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 

  <RadioGroup 
     xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:orientation="vertical"> 
       <RadioButton 
            android:id="@+id/radio_blue" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="@string/pirates" 
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/> 
       <RadioButton 
            android:id="@+id/radio_red" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/ninjas" 
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/> 
  </RadioGroup>
```

Comment: post your code..

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical"> <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_blue" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/pirates" android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/> <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_red" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/ninjas" android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/> </RadioGroup>

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided in the comment:

```xml
<RadioGroup
    xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RadioButton 
        android:id="@+id/radio_blue" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/pirates" 
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>

    <RadioButton 
        android:id="@+id/radio_red" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/ninjas" 
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>

</RadioGroup>
```

In order to handle the OnClick events, you have to use an Activity class to handle the action.

You can do something like this to start:

```java
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView title;
    RadioButton red_button, blue_button, ...;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.[Your XML Name]);


        //Getting Widget References
        title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
        red_button = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio_red);


        //Handle OnClick Events
        red_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                title.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
            }
        });
    }
}
```